# How to convert Asp.net Web Project to Website...?

Tags: asp.net

i have code in **asp.net web Project** ... i want to convert that code to **asp.net web site** .. can any one help me for convertion of my code....

Comment: This is inadvisable for many reasons (and depending on your project, possibly impossible).  Are you sure it's what you want?

Comment: Are you looking to host your website. If so than take a look at [this](http://www.microsoft.com/web/hosting/home)

Comment: If all you intend to do is create website for public viewing then do publish the Project and then create virtual directory pointing to this newly published directory

Answer (score 0):

- Open the project as a WebSite in VisualStudio.
- Save a new Solution file for it.
- Delete all the "*.designer" files.
- In the code-infront of every user interface file (*.ASCX and *.ASPX), change the Page directive attribute from "codebehind" to "codefile".